What usage should 'more than but trivial length' be recognised as?
[Rodney Huddleston Geoffrey K Pullum. (2017). The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language. p.527.]

Adjectives and adverbs are numerous in English; there are many
thousands of each, and they are very frequent in use: almost every
sentence of more than but trivial length contains adjectives and/or
adverbs.

Is this a fixed usage? Or are some elements omitted?

The word "but" here means "only". I don't believe omitting it changes the meaning of this sentence.

Very awkward "more than but"  They may be grammarians but they sure can't write.

I think this locution may be more common in Edinburgh than it is in Washington D.C.

The grammar is fine, and nothing is omitted. 'But' can mean 'only' - a boy of but seven years, a walk of but ten yards. This usage is probably seen as old-fashioned by many people.
The sentence is discussing 'any sentence of more than only trivial length'. The word 'only' serves to emphasise the smallness of the length, and can be omitted.

but adverb (ONLY)
formal
only; just:
She's but a young girl!

But (Cambridge Dictionary)

more than only trivial length is just as awkward in my book but your explanation is good. They just ain't writers. And make reading their book very tiresome.

@Lambie - Criticising Huddleston & Pullum? Wash your mouth out!

Actually, I call them Huddle and Puddle or Huddlum and Pudlum. You could at least show that you are being funny, innit?// [By the way, in a police procedural, they were following a car and kept saying the car was doing reciprocal? Is that British copper parlance for summat? Thanks, I will delete your answer.]

@Lambie - I gather that someone called de Haan had the temerity to criticise them in the early 2000s, and they, unusually, answered back. Perhaps this is old hat?

@Lambie - can't help with the 'reciprocal' thing, sorry.

Yeah, well, there are others: However, there is one
important area in which the Huddleston and Pullum work fails to match the quality of the
Quirk et al. volume: that is in its description and analysis of the English verbal system. https://muse.jhu.edu/article/174185/pdf Don't even mention phrasal verbs. The tense issue is not credible criticism. Read the para.
